# how to replace last comma in a line with a string in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I trying to insert a string in every line except for first and last lines in a file, but not able to get it done, can anyone give some clue how to achieve? Thanks in advance.

How to replace last comma in a line with a string xxxxx (except for first and last rows) 
using unix

Original File

```
00,SRI,BOM,FF,000004,20120808030100,20120907094412,"GTEXPR","SRIVIM","8894-7577","SRIVIM@GTEXPR."
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,GEB,,230900,02BLYPO
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,TCM,231040,231100,01
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,UPW,231240,231300,01
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,UFG,231700,231900,01
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,FTG,232140,232200,01
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,BOR,232340,232400,01
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,BAY,232640,232700,01
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,RWD,233400,,01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0800,NMJWJB,U,NM,CCL,,101400,02CHLSU
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0800,NMJWJB,U,NM,PAR,101540,101700,01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0800,NMJWJB,U,NM,MCE,101840,101900,01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0800,NMJWJB,U,NM,SSS,102140,102200,09
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0800,NMJWJB,U,NM,FSS,102600,,01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0802,NMJWJB,U,NM,CCL,,103700,01CHLSU
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0802,NMJWJB,U,NM,PAR,103940,104000,01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0802,NMJWJB,U,NM,MCE,104140,104200,01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0802,NMJWJB,U,NM,SSS,104440,104500,09
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0802,NMJWJB,U,NM,FSS,105000,,01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,GEB,,230900,02BLYSU
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,TCM,231040,231100,01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,UPW,231240,231300,01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,UFG,231700,231900,01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,FTG,232140,232200,01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,BOR,232340,232400,01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,BAY,232640,232700,01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,RWD,233400,,01
99,SRI,FF,28
```

Expected File

```
00,SRI,BOM,FF,000004,20120808030100,20120907094412,"GTEXPR","SRIVIM","8894-7577","SRIVIM@GTEXPR."
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,GEB,,230900,xxxxx02BLYPO
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,TCM,231040,xxxxx231100,01
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,UPW,231240,xxxxx231300,01
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,UFG,231700,xxxxx231900,01
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,FTG,232140,xxxxx232200,01
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,BOR,232340,xxxxx232400,01
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,BAY,232640,xxxxx232700,01
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,RWD,233400,,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0800,NMJWJB,U,NM,CCL,,101400,xxxxx02CHLSU
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0800,NMJWJB,U,NM,PAR,101540,101700,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0800,NMJWJB,U,NM,MCE,101840,101900,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0800,NMJWJB,U,NM,SSS,102140,102200,xxxxx09
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0800,NMJWJB,U,NM,FSS,102600,,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0802,NMJWJB,U,NM,CCL,,103700,xxxxx01CHLSU
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0802,NMJWJB,U,NM,PAR,103940,104000,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0802,NMJWJB,U,NM,MCE,104140,104200,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0802,NMJWJB,U,NM,SSS,104440,104500,xxxxx09
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0802,NMJWJB,U,NM,FSS,105000,,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,GEB,,230900,xxxxx02BLYSU
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,TCM,231040,231100,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,UPW,231240,231300,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,UFG,231700,231900,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,FTG,232140,232200,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,BOR,232340,232400,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,BAY,232640,232700,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,RWD,233400,,xxxxx01
99,SRI,FF,28
```

Comment: Looks like you're not replacing the last comma, your adding a value after it. Which do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` can be quite useful for manipulating data files like this one. Here's a one-liner that does more-or-less what you want. It prepends the string "xxxxx" to the twelfth field of each input line that has at least twelve fields.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NF>11{$12="xxxxx"$12}{print}' 16006747.txt 
00,SRI,BOM,FF,000004,20120808030100,20120907094412,"GTEXPR","SRIVIM","8894-7577","SRIVIM@GTEXPR."
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,GEB,,230900,xxxxx02BLYPO
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,TCM,231040,231100,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,UPW,231240,231300,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,UFG,231700,231900,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,FTG,232140,232200,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,BOR,232340,232400,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,BAY,232640,232700,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,NMNN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,RWD,233400,,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0800,NMJWJB,U,NM,CCL,,101400,xxxxx02CHLSU
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0800,NMJWJB,U,NM,PAR,101540,101700,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0800,NMJWJB,U,NM,MCE,101840,101900,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0800,NMJWJB,U,NM,SSS,102140,102200,xxxxx09
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0800,NMJWJB,U,NM,FSS,102600,,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0802,NMJWJB,U,NM,CCL,,103700,xxxxx01CHLSU
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0802,NMJWJB,U,NM,PAR,103940,104000,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0802,NMJWJB,U,NM,MCE,104140,104200,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0802,NMJWJB,U,NM,SSS,104440,104500,xxxxx09
10,SRI,FF,BUN,0802,NMJWJB,U,NM,FSS,105000,,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,GEB,,230900,xxxxx02BLYSU
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,TCM,231040,231100,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,UPW,231240,231300,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,UFG,231700,231900,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,FTG,232140,232200,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,BOR,232340,232400,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,BAY,232640,232700,xxxxx01
10,SRI,FF,BUN,3112,NMNSME,U,NM,RWD,233400,,xxxxx01
99,SRI,FF,28
```